# How to get value of title attribute from a selected option in DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html `select` element, which includes three `option` elements. I have written a jquery code, which gives me the value of the title attribut from the current selected option element and saves that value in a variable (on the fly!).

But I would like to read a title attribute from an option value, which was not selected on the fly and which was already shown as selected value in my xhtml page, if the page was loaded as first.

This is my jQuery code and the second coderow doesn´t work correct:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var optionElements = jQuery(jQuerySelektorHTMLSelectElement).children();
   var OptionField = optionElements.find("[value=" + selectedValue + "]");
   var OptionFieldTitleAttribut = OptionFeld.attr("title"); 

}
```

How can I find an option element, which was not selected on the fly but is selected, if the xhtml page was loaded?

Answer (score 3):

If your variable `jQuerySelektorHTMLSelectElement` is well-named, you don't have to call `children` :

```
var selectElement = $(jQuerySelektorHTMLSelectElement); // <- remove children here
var OptionField = selectElement.find("[value=" + selectedValue + "]");
var OptionFieldTitleAttribut = OptionField.attr("title");
```

The `find` method already look for the selector in the children...

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48cLA/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**html**

```
<select id="test">
    <option customAttr="a">test1</option>
    <option customAttr="b">test2</option>
    <option customAttr="c" selected="selected">test3</option>
    <option customAttr="d">test4</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
$(function(){
  console.log($("#test").find("option:selected").attr("customAttr"));
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QESE4/5/)